# auto login acegi security

Tags: security, authentication, spring-security

Is there a way to avoid form based login in servlet application which uses acegi security module? I want to pass somehow login and password to URL. I tried to call something like this:

```java
GrantedAuthority[] grantedAuthorities = new GrantedAuthority[] {new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_ADMIN")};
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("admin", "passwordofadmin", grantedAuthorities);
WebAuthenticationDetails authdetails = (WebAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();
HttpSession session = event.getSession();
ProviderManager pm = (ProviderManager)WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(session.getServletContext()).getBean("authenticationManager");
pm.doAuthentication(authentication);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

in handler of `HttpSessionCreatedEvent` event, and I received `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` event, but then `Failure` event also received and authentication form displayed.

Answer (score 0):

First you must override UserDetailsService in xml. Something like this:

```
<bean id="userService" class="com.security.UserSecurityService" >
    ...
</bean>
```

Then write your own service.like:

```
public class UserSecurityService implements UserDetailsService {
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException{

User user =userDAO.findByUsername(username);
GrantedAuthority[] grantedRoles = {new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER")};

        secUsr = new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), true, grantedRoles);
```

I hope this will be helpful for you